# Eclipse C/C++ projects on mac

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, macos

I am using Eclipse classic 4.2.1 (Juno) on my new mac to develop c/c++ programs. When I create a new project their is a choice of "Toolchains" to use: Cross GCC, MacOSX GCC and XL C/C++ Tool Chain.
Which one should I choose? I also use the mac terminal to run, make and vim the same code sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe GCC is in common use if your app will run both in mac and windows

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac OS X Luna(eclipse 8.4) but they are the same edition in general. Just goto the Help tab and click on "***Install new software...***" or anything similar to that. Type this in the big obvious add software link (pretty much just the test input at the top of the new opened window):
**http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/juno**
if you think juno can handle the newest version, type this in:
**http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4**
Select every thing and proceed with the download.
You should now be able to create C/C++ projects and source files. I found this to be slightly buggy, like sometimes not include the standard C++ library, or std does not even exist but this should work if you install the correct version.